# Sharepoint permissions. Require multiple groups

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have a permission question I hope someone can help me with.

I have setup permission groups for each department in an organization, i.e. “Dept-1”, "Dept-2", etc.  My plan is to put people in these groups so they correspond with the department they work for.  Next I’m setting up groups that correspond to areas of work, i.e. “Area-Tech”, “Area-Manager”.  What I’d like to be able to do is give access to a list where a user needs to be in both “Dept-1” and “Area-Manager” in order to view and edit items.  If a user is just in “Dept-1” they shouldn’t have access.

Can this be done?  Maybe there is another way.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you will need a 3rd group "Dept1 Area Mgrs" or something.
The permissions in SharePoint are "OR"-based, not "AND"-based.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Audiences, but remember that this is not a security feature and information will only be hidden from the users.

Is it possible to say that all users that are Area Manager have view and write permissions and all others only have view permissions?